# How to use SKConstraint in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a moving camera in my scene, which always follows my player. But I also have some other content(On screen controls) which I want to stay in a single place on the screen, but when the camera moves, The controls are moving away to. How would I go about doing this. I have searched a lot, and found the `SKConstraint`, but I couldn't find any tutorials to use it in swift 3.

Should I be using the `SKConstraint`? If yes, how can I use it, if no, how do I keep the controls at a certain position on the screen at all times.

I also know that I could change the position of the controls in the update method, but I do not want to do that as there are many on screen controls, and I try to refrain from writing code in the update method as much as possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `SKConstraint` to cause a camera to follow a character.

First, create a camera node and a hero and add them to the scene

```
let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

addChild(hero)
camera = cameraNode
addChild(cameraNode)
```

Next, create a constraint and assign it to the camera node's `constraints` property

```
let range = SKRange(constantValue:0)
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: hero)
cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
```

Lastly, if you have controls or labels that need to be at fixed locations relative to the camera, you can add them to the camera node

```
let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 123")

// Position the label relative to the camera node
label.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
cameraNode.addChild(label)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, so the trick was to add the nodes to the SKCameraNode.